# How to detect unused css-modules classes

Tags: reactjs, css-modules, react-css-modules

Does anyone know any tool which would help to highlight classes that are not used in css-modules?
Recently I have added typescript-plugin-css-modules to my project which helps me to detect if I use non existent class names in JSX, but now I also want to be able to detect unused classes in module.css as it unnecessary adds dead css code to the bundle.

Comment: There is April of 2021 and the question is still actual.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to detect unused CSS module then there are a few ways to do it:

1. Using chrome's developer tools:
   [image]
2. Use something like `purifycss`:

Installation:

```
npm i -D purify-css
```

Usage:

```
import purify from "purify-css"
const purify = require("purify-css")

let content = ""
let css = ""
let options = {
    output: "filepath/output.css"
}
purify(content, css, options)
```

> A function that takes content (HTML/JS/PHP/etc) and CSS, and returns only the used CSS.
> PurifyCSS does not modify the original CSS files. You can write to a new file, like minification.
> If your application is using a CSS framework, this is especially useful as many selectors are often unused.

Read more [here](https://github.com/purifycss/purifycss)

3. Use uncss

Installation:

```
npm install -g uncss
```

Usage within NodeJS:

```
var uncss = require('uncss');

var files   = ['my', 'array', 'of', 'HTML', 'files', 'or', 'http://urls.com'],
    options = {
        banner       : false,
        csspath      : '../public/css/',
        htmlroot     : 'public',
        ignore       : ['#added_at_runtime', /test\-[0-9]+/],
        ignoreSheets : [/fonts.googleapis/],
        inject       : function(window) { window.document.querySelector('html').classList.add('no-csscalc', 'csscalc'); },
        jsdom        : {
            userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3 like Mac OS X)',
        },
        media        : ['(min-width: 700px) handheld and (orientation: landscape)'],
        raw          : 'h1 { color: green }',
        report       : false,
        strictSSL    : true,
        stylesheets  : ['lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css', 'src/public/css/main.css'],
        timeout      : 1000,
        uncssrc      : '.uncssrc',
        userAgent    : 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3 like Mac OS X)',
    };

uncss(files, options, function (error, output) {
    console.log(output);
});

/* Look Ma, no options! */
uncss(files, function (error, output) {
    console.log(output);
});

/* Specifying raw HTML */
var rawHtml = '...';

uncss(rawHtml, options, function (error, output) {
    console.log(output);
});
```

> UnCSS is a tool that removes unused CSS from your stylesheets. It works across multiple files and supports Javascript-injected CSS.

Read more [here](https://github.com/uncss/uncss)

N.B: There are other packages as well. But I've personally used uncss and purifycss which I mentioned here

Comment: What I was looking for is more of like that it would be able to detect during the runtime unused classes that are defined in css files while running localhost.

Answer (score 2):

If you have TypeScript this can help:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-plugin-css-modules

Two eslint plugins can help if you don't have TypeScript

1. [eslint-plugin-postcss-modules](https://github.com/bmatcuk/eslint-plugin-postcss-modules) last updated 2021
2. [eslint-plugin-css-modules](https://github.com/atfzl/eslint-plugin-css-modules) last updated 2019

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).